# Choosing a specific style of a font in CSS when developing locally

Tags: html, css, fonts, localhost, webfonts

As I'm building locally, I don't need to worry about webfonts. In order to update the live site all I need to do is upload my amended stylesheet to the server.

I have the font `Trade Gothic LT Std` installed on my computer, and have styled some elements like so:

```
.element {
    font-family: Trade Gothic LT Std;
}
```

However I need to style some elements as `Trade Gothic LT Std Bold Condensed No. 20`. I've tried specifying this like so:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Trade Gothic LT Std Bold Condensed No. 20";
}
```

But with no luck. So I've also tried something like so:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Trade Gothic LT Std";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: "Bold Condensed No. 20";
}
```

But then all I get is the standard `Trade Gothic LT Std` font.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Here is the font info if that helps

> PostScript name   TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20
>
> Full name Trade Gothic LT Std Bold Condensed No. 20
>
> Family    Trade Gothic LT Std
>
> Style Bold Condensed No. 20

Comment: Have you tried the PostScript name? `font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20'`

Comment: @JonUleis ah yep I meant to say I tried that too but unfortunately it just breaks it and displays the default browser font

Comment: Serious question: what does "As I'm building locally, I don't need to worry about webfonts." mean? Because those are two fairly unrelated notions. "webfonts" are not a thing, it's a misnomer. What we have are fonts, that you load through an `@font-face` declaration, using `src: url(...)`, and you do that regardless on where the fonts actually live: if you have the fonts in your own dirs, it's a relative url. If not, it's an absolute url. In both cases, you are using "webfonts", irrespective of local dev.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was thinking that, if you had a font installed on your machine, you'd be able to load it without `@font-face`?

Comment: Yes, but then that works for *only you* because you have no guarantee that anyone else has that font installed. To make things more interestinged, even if they do have a font installed that their OS claims has the same name that you're using, there is zero guarantee that it is the same font or even the same *version* of the font. As such, relying on `local()` is typically a really bad idea if you care about things looking the way they should look.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I understand that, but the live site is already set up with `@font-face` on the server... all I need to do is make some changes to the layout etc (which I'm doing locally)... but I'm trying to set it up so that I can load the font from my installed fonts on my machine, as I'm unable to get FTP access to download everything as it is

Comment: yeah so don't do that. Just use the server version so you know you're testing against the real thing without any special cheats? you have internet, and your browser caches the font. Why are you bringing FTP into this, though, that's not where webcontent lives is it? Don't tell me the `@font-face` rule tries to load the font over ftp instead of http... if so, fix *that* instead O_o;

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the source of the file if it is not system installed font something like this.

```
@font-face {
font-family: fontname;
src: url(localfonturl);
}
```

Then use the name 'fontname' where ever you want.

```
div {
font-family: fontname;
}
```

Try .ttf type font file since it will support in all major browsers.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I don't have a `.ttf` but have tried specifying the link anyway like so — `../Users/username/Library/Fonts/TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20.otf'` — but can't seem to get it to work... do you know how I would specify an absolute local URL on a Mac?

Comment: for local font, it's not `src: url`, it's `src: local` (typically in addition to remotes, so `src: url(...) format("..."), local(TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20) format("opentype")`)